# python text to morse translator breaks in mid-way

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, morse-code

As a practice in python, I tried to make a text to morse translator. but it breaks after executing only once. Could you help me figure out the problem? (It's probably in morse function) function `beep` is for sound, dictionary `item_list` is a pack of every character's special code.

```
import winsound
import time
def beep(char):
    if char == 'a':
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == 'b':
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == 'c':
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == 'd':
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == 'e':
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == 'f':
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == 'g':
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == 'h':
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == 'i':
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == 'j':
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == 'k':
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == 'l':
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == 'm':
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == 'n':
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == 'o':
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == 'p':
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == 'q':
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == 'r':
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == 's':
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == 't':
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == 'u':
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == 'v':
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == 'w':
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == 'x':
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == 'y':
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == 'z':
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == '1':
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == '2':
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == '3':
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == '4':
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == '5':
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == '6':
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == '7':
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == '8':
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == '9':
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == '0':
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == '.':
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == '-':
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == '/':
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == ',':
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == '?':
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 500)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
        winsound.Beep(500, 150)
        time.sleep(150)
    elif char == ' ':
        print("\t")
    else:
        print("unknown")
        winsound.Beep(500, 1000)
        time.sleep(150)


item_dict = {
    'a': '.- ',
    'b': '-... ',
    'c': '-.-. ',
    'd': '-.. ',
    'e': '. ',
    'f': '..-. ',
    'g': '--. ',
    'h': '.... ',
    'i': '.. ',
    'j': '.--- ',
    'k': '-.- ',
    'l': '.-.. ',
    'm': '-- ',
    'n': '-. ',
    'o': '--- ',
    'p': '.--. ',
    'q': '--.- ',
    'r': '.-. ',
    's': '... ',
    't': '- ',
    'u': '..- ',
    'v': '...- ',
    'w': '.-- ',
    'x': '-..- ',
    'y': '-.-- ',
    'z': '--.. ',
    '0': '----- ',
    '1': '.---- ',
    '2': '..--- ',
    '3': '...-- ',
    '4': '....- ',
    '5': '..... ',
    '6': '-.... ',
    '7': '--... ',
    '8': '---.. ',
    '9': '----. ',
    ' ': '\t',
    '.': '.-.-.- ',
    ',': '--..-- ',
    '?': '..--.. ',
    '-': '-...- ',
    '/': '-..-. '
}


def morse():
    x = input("?")
    name_list = list(x)
    for x in name_list:
        print(item_dict[f"{x}"])
        beep(x)
    morse()


print('''text to morse-text
    enter the text you want''')


morse()
```

Comment: Why does everyone think they need to convert a string to a list before looping over it with `for-in`?

Comment: There is really no need to add your email address, let alone your Instagram account, to your question.

Comment: Since `x` is already a string, you don't need to write `f"{x}"`, just write `x` there.

Comment: Instead of all those `if` statements, you should just loop over the characters in `item_dict()` and beep the appropriate length for a dot or dash.

Comment: You do use a recursive call to `morse`. Try to use a outer loop (with exit condition)

Comment: Could you describe the problem better? Is it stopping after the first character, or after the first call to `morse()`?

Comment: @Barmar 1- I converted it into a list to make possibility of using more functions on it.
                 2-Yes now I see f is not necessary
                 3-I guess I could make another dictionary
                 4- after first call

Comment: What about `time.sleep(150)`? Did you mean `time.sleep(0.15)`?

Comment: @PiCTo The site wasn't letting me post it because "the code was too long". Nothing else reached My mind. Sorry.

Comment: @quamrana No it means the process stops for 150 milliseconds. It's for the delay between each character's beep.

Comment: So in what way is `time.sleep(150)` pausing for 150 milliseconds?

Comment: The argument to `time.sleep()` is seconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: @Barmar What is wrong with python? I shouldn't have left c family.

Comment: Steady on. There are 5 people here trying to help you.

Comment: @quamrana Thanks. The problem was with Sleep. It takes args in secs not milliscs.

Comment: @SorooshYadollahPour The C `sleep()` function is also in seconds.

Comment: @Barmar No in c++ windows.h lib there is Sleep function in millis and I always use it

Comment: That's not the standard C `sleep()` function, that's something specific to Windows.

Comment: So the program didn't `break`, it just hung up. It must have also printed something out, but you didn't mention that.

Comment: @quamrana Yes. Seconds. Milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, it should be `sleep(.15)`

Then, your `beep` function is too *"painful"* to watch, here is a suggestion:

```
import winsound
import time


def beep(char):
    """translates a char into morse-code dashes and dots, and beeps them"""
    sound = {'-': 500, '.': 150, ' ': 10}
    for dashdot in item_dict.get(char, ' '):
        if dashdot == '\t':
            dashdot = ' '
#         print(f'{dashdot}', end='')
        winsound.Beep(500, sound[dashdot])
        time.sleep(.15)
#     print(' ', end='')


item_dict = {
    'a': '.- ',
    'b': '-... ',
    'c': '-.-. ',
    'd': '-.. ',
    'e': '. ',
    'f': '..-. ',
    'g': '--. ',
    'h': '.... ',
    'i': '.. ',
    'j': '.--- ',
    'k': '-.- ',
    'l': '.-.. ',
    'm': '-- ',
    'n': '-. ',
    'o': '--- ',
    'p': '.--. ',
    'q': '--.- ',
    'r': '.-. ',
    's': '... ',
    't': '- ',
    'u': '..- ',
    'v': '...- ',
    'w': '.-- ',
    'x': '-..- ',
    'y': '-.-- ',
    'z': '--.. ',
    '0': '----- ',
    '1': '.---- ',
    '2': '..--- ',
    '3': '...-- ',
    '4': '....- ',
    '5': '..... ',
    '6': '-.... ',
    '7': '--... ',
    '8': '---.. ',
    '9': '----. ',
    ' ': '\t',
    '.': '.-.-.- ',
    ',': '--..-- ',
    '?': '..--.. ',
    '-': '-...- ',
    '/': '-..-. '
}


def morse():
    x = input()
    # x = item_dict.keys()
    name_list = list(x)
    for c in x:
        beep(c)

print('''text to morse-text
    enter the text you want''')

morse()
```

**debug output:**

```
.-  -...  -.-.  -..  .  ..-.  --.  ....  ..  .---  -.-  .-..  --  -.  ---  .--.  --.-  .-.  ...  -  ..-  ...-  .--  -..-  -.--  --..  -----  .----  ..---  ...--  ....-  .....  -....  --...  ---..  ----.    .-.-.-  --..--  ..--..  -...-  -..-.
```

Comment: Painful :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: LOL - ok, I put it in quotes! ;-)

Comment: Your answer wouldn't reach your mind if you started programming with c limits. These combinations are like a joke in c. Not yet suited in py.

Comment: his `item_dict` have spaces `' '`..instead of remove all the spaces , i added modified to `sound = {'-': 500, '.': 150,' ':0}`

Comment: i got error `KeyError: '\t'` at spaces...um , how to solve that?

Comment: You could make a beep dictionary to make it easier

Comment: Fixed - the old fashion way!