# how to set the cursor back in previous line in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In one part of my Py code, I have to print an specific text per each char in a list.
for example:

```
dictx{
'a': 'd',
'b': 'f',
'c': 'x'
}
x = 'abc'
for y in x:
    print(dictx[y])
```

but as you probably know, The cursor goes to the next line after each "print" so these will be written in three lines. Do you know anyway to set the cursor back? (With just a "\t" after each print)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`end`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) parameter of the `print` function *(default value of the `end` parameter is `'\n'`)*:

```
dictx = {
'a': 'd',
'b': 'f',
'c': 'x'
}
x = 'abc'
for y in x:
    print(dictx[y], end='\t')
```

Output:

```
d   f   x
```

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to concatenate your items in a string variable, and print the final concatenated items using print.
Here is the code:

```
dictx{
'a': 'd',
'b': 'f',
'c': 'x'
}
x = 'abc'
concatenate = ''
for y in x:
    concatenate = concatenate + '\t' + dictx[y]
print(concatenate)
```

Comment: Also a way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:
`print("\t".join(dictx.values()))`

This also does not require you to do the for loop

Comment: No No No. It was an example. The loop may contain different combination of chars. Full project: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64964697/python-text-to-morse-translator-breaks-in-mid-way/64965177?noredirect=1#comment114854155_64965177